# New Windows 7 Install Crashing

Tags: windows-7, windows, crash, internet-explorer-8

One big reboot crash and one smaller crash already, 15 minutes in.

Did a basic install of Windows 7, installed Chrome and Firefox. I had just finished loading up my gmail account in Chrome/Firefox to show the speed difference and we'd thought it would be hilarious to see how slow IE8 was. :P

Just about as IE8 was done opening, the computer's screen goes black.

After a restart and a couple minutes, Explorer crashes as well.

What is going on? This install is only 15-20 minutes old. :P

Comment: Installed updates. No crashes so far but not holding my breath. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be a few things.

If this is an existing machine and you have had problems in the past, I would recommend  that you use [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest86.org) and do a scan of your system just to make sure there is no faulty memory.

Next, or if you have had no issues in the past, Windows 7 is a leap forward, however, there are a few out of the box drivers which are pretty awful (even though they are signed). I have had a lot of problems with Realtek network drivers that basically cause a BSOD whenever (in the movie speed style) the network reaches above 70% utilization. You may be affected by this or another driver so I would recommend upgrading to the latest available versions.

Again, I can say 100% sure that Realtek drivers have problems and updates available [here](http://www.realtek.com.tw), I have not seen BSOD with other manufacturers but I have seen much increased performance by upgrading.

Lastly, if this doesn't help, I would recommend downloading [Nirsoft Bluescreen View](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) which can tell you what caused BSODs on your system. If you edit your question and post them, we can help you further.

Comment: Updating drivers fixed any issues (so far). Thanks!! :)